# Find products of digits in R

Tags: r

Can someone help me fix the code to get the product of digit (example 457) in R programming? I tried to run this code:

```
number <- 457
product <- 1
while(number > 0) {
  product <- product * (number%%10)
  number <- number/10
} 
print(product)
```

but it keeps on giving me 0. I can't find any code available for R so I tried to revise the code from java, but it can't give me the answer(140)that i was looking for. Can someone help me fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick function using base R. One easy way is to convert the number to a string, split it, convert back to numeric, and then use prod()

```
number_product <- function(x){
prod(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(as.character(x),split = ""))))
}
number_product(457)
```

Comment: thanks for the help! But what if the requirement is a code without using function?

Comment: `prod(as.numeric(str_split(x, "", simplify = TRUE)))` is a slightly-shorter version, avoids the need for `unlist` and `as.character`

Comment: @cee_zee then you could just use e.g. `prod(as.numeric(str_split(457, "", simplify = TRUE)))`. But I'd think a function is more useful unless you only ever want to use 457 :)

Comment: will this be the same code I can use if loop is asked?

Answer (score 1):

This is a math solution that doesn't change your input into a string.

```
ten <- 10^seq_len(ceiling(log10(number)))
prod(number %% ten %/% (ten/10))
```

---

If you are interested in time efficiency, this solution is faster:

```
number <- 123456789

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
 math = {ten <- 10^seq_len(ceiling(log10(number)))
         prod(number %% ten %/% (ten/10))},
 string = prod(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(as.character(number),split = ""))))
)
#> Unit: microseconds
#>    expr  min   lq   mean median    uq   max neval
#>    math  4.4  5.1  6.649   5.70  6.60  48.9   100
#>  string 10.4 11.1 15.700  11.85 16.85 139.7   100
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is using `utf8ToInt` + `as.character` like below

```
> prod(utf8ToInt(as.character(number)) - utf8ToInt('0'))
[1] 140
```